# Source Tree issue when Mac crashed

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have an issue with mu source tree. My mac crashed whilst I was committing something and automatically pushing it to one of the branches in my repo.

When I restarted my mac my Master branch was missing from this one local repo.

Whenever I try to commit the changes so I can change to a different branch I get the following:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree commit -q -F /var/folders/fz/vqrlp05n24gcr0vdp92qyvfjvzfz2f/T/SourceTreeTemp.AlvKt1 
error: unable to resolve reference HEAD: No such file or directory
fatal: cannot lock HEAD ref
Completed with errors, see above
```

And it won't actually commit anything.

When I try and change the branch I get:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree checkout 83382244_Sign_In_Person_Button_-_Update 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    file1
    file2
    file3
    file4
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Completed with errors, see above
```

And it is not changing branches.

If I try and create a Branch I am getting:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree branch test 
fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.
Completed with errors, see above
```

When I run `git reset HEAD` in the terminal I get the following:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

and when I run `git checkout master` I get:

```
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/master.
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    file1
    file2
    file3
    file4
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I am stumped :/

Comment: Sounds like the easiest thing is to make a backup of your local files and then re-checkout the project from your repo.  There is probably a fancy way to fix this using various git commands, but re-creating it will probably be the easiest solution

Comment: Yeah I thought that, the issue is if I do a backup of browser.plist and hostingservices.plist it will just recreate the issue won't it? I read somewhere online it's possibly a corrupt file, although all of my files can open perfectly fine :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `browser.plist`, but if you delete your local project (or move it to a temp space), and then re-checkout from your remote repo, then the project should be in a good state.  You can then recreate your changes (ie copy the modified files back over) and it should work.

Comment: Sorry! Both files are the ones you need to backup to keep all of your branches and local repo bookmarks to be able to transfer them to a new computer

Comment: Think we are misunderstanding each other.  Where is your project located on disk?  ie `C:\Projects\Example`

Comment: Yeah I have a mac though :)

Answer (score 0):

I got someone in my office to give me a hand... I used the following (from my repo source folder)

```
git status
git stash
```

Neither of these worked correctly. So I did the following:

```
cd ..
rm -r src
git clone "SSH clone URL" src
git pull "SSH clone URL"
git pull "SSH clone URL" master
git push "SSH clone URL" master
git checkout -b branch_name
git pull "SSH clone URL" branch_name
```

Then I had to go back into source tree, select my master branch, locate the relevant branches that I need to be able to switch between by using the "Jump To:" dropdown at the top.

Once located I had to double click on the branch in the graph and checkout the remote branch.. repeating this for all branches that I needed in my Source Tree...

Not sure if this was a long winded way but it worked!